# Windows 8 sorting by name

Tags: windows-8, sorting

I have a lot of documents and when I sorting them by Name, it looks like this:

```
Story - descriptions.docx
Story.docx
Tale - descriptions.docx
Tale - maps.jpg
Tale v2.docx
Tale.docx
```

Why it is sorted that way, and not with `Story.docx` at the beginning before `Story - descriptions.docx`?

Answer (score 0):

This is just how sorting works.

Looking at the ascii character table the `.` (dot/period) comes **after** the "" (space).

Even if you hide the know extensions in Windows it is sorted as if they are there.

You can test this by making files without the `.docx`. (or deleting it from your documents) You'll see then that you get your expected sorting. But with the `.docx` after the filename, files without text after i.e. `Story`, are listed after `Story xxx` because of this `.` (dot) coming after space.

If you really want the `Story.docx` to come first you can rename the `Story - descriptions.docx` to `Story_- descriptions.docx`. Notice the `_` instead of the space. The `_` comes **after** the `.` (dot) in sorting.

Comment: I recently moved from XP, and sorting there is as it should be. That is why I confused... and I rather don't want rename all my files ;)

Comment: I know there is a setting in gpedit.msc to ignore the sorting of numbers. Maybe there is a setting for this but i haven't looked for it.

Comment: I just tested this in Windows XP with your filenames and there they are sorted the same as Windows 7/8 (for my Windows XP setup).

Comment: Strange. Maybe this is because my XP is in polish version, and win8 english... and this is default setting. Crap.